# Isnull equivalent in SOLR

Tags: solr, datastax, datastax-enterprise, solr-query-syntax

My query in sql server is like `where isnull(id,'3') = 3` which would give me all null values as well as values equal to 3. I want to achieve the same in SOLR but not able to get it. I tried

```
id:3 OR -id:[* TO *]
```

but it gave me no result whereas on `-id:[* TO *]` it gives me correct amount of results. How do I make the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe the issue here is the precedence of the operators, - is being applied to both condition or something like that (might be a bug), anyway, this works:

```
q=(-id:[* TO *]) OR id:3
```

Answer (score 0):

try with `id:('' TO *)` OR `id:3`.